# How to change the graphics driver from i915 to intel?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

Does anyone know how to change the graphics driver in 11.04 from i915 to intel?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to do anything, the "intel" driver covers i915 card already and it's the default driver in Ubuntu anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create an xorg.conf file by typing:

`sudo Xorg -configure`

and then edit the `[Device]` section with the driver you want.

Answer (score -4):

Also, I would add this PPA... https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

Comment: Can you motivate that? Why should he install that? What is it in the first place? What are the risks?